# Array offset error on type bool and null, due to admin-bar support added

Tags: theme-development, add-theme-support

I recently started working on a new theme and added admin bar theme support by using this snippet of code in the functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support('admin-bar');
```

However, I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\Users\local-domain-path\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-admin-bar.php on line 63
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Correct me if I am wrong, but this is a standard prebuilt WP function for theme support no? so why isn't it working properly?

And what can I do to get this error fixed? Thank you

Comment: Do you have the statement wrapped in a function and using `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_function_name' );`?

Comment: @YourManDan Yes, that is exactly how it is coded. I tried it outside the function as a stand-alone but I received the same message and I also tried changing "after_setup_theme" to "init". Same error, I didn't think it would work but gave it a shot anyways.

Comment: @YourManDan I decided to change it to this.

`add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' );`

However, while I do see space created at the top of the browser for an admin bar, it unfortunately doesn't display any content or options. What am I missing? Thank you